# Add site logo on standard paypal redirected page in php

Tags: php, paypal

I want to add my site's logo on paypal redirected page from my site to paypal, for payment.
Any one know how to do that

Comment: just hack the PayPal.com and put your logo there, why not

Comment: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/cowp_summary-outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on the PayPal website:
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/cowp_summary-outside

Comment: Note that to provide custom images, you need to be able to serve them out as `https://`, at least it used to be that way two years ago. This can be a major headache if your site is not SSL enabled. There are hosting companies specialized on hosting images through SSL.